# Rails Mailer multipart + inline images: no html alternative in Apple Mail, TB

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Using rails 3.0.10, we need to send mail messages with html and plain text alternative where the html part references images sent along as inline attachments.

The code:

```
def invite(secure_share)
  @share = secure_share
  attachments.inline['download.png'] = File.read "#{Rails.root}/public/images/download.png"
  mail( :to => secure_share.recipient, 
        :from => 'dummy@example.com',
      )  do |format|
    format.html { render :layout => 'cargo_secureshare_mailer' }
    format.text
  end
end
```

The templates are in place, the inline attachment works and we get a mail with the following structure:

- Content-type "multipart/related"
- Part "multipart/alternative"

  - Part "text/html"
  - Part "text/plain"
- Part "image/png" (inline attachment)

Neither Apple Mail nor Thunderbird seem to like this, they will not show the HTML version but only a text version with two "normal" attachments. It seems like the multipart structure is wrong - shouldn't it have "multipart/alternative" as the content type and then "multipart/related" as a wrapper for the html with inline attachments?

Anyone a hint how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Found here: http://www.shortround.net/2011/04/07/multipart-alternative-multipart-related-email-with-actionmailer-for-rails-3/

It almost works. i.e. it works for regular attchments but fails for inlined